# Laravel 5 url() doesn't contain scheme

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm quite new in Laravel.

I'm working on an existing Laravel 5.8 project. I installed it locally with HomeStead.

I noticed a strange behaviour on redirects: considering my homepage is `http://project.test/`, when there is a redirection, say to `/redirected`, Laravel sets the location to `http://project.test/://project.test/redirected`! As I tried to figure out wat was going on, I saw that the `url('/')` Laravel function gives me `://project.test` instead of `http://project.test`.

`request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()` gives `http://project.test`.

Example in web.php:

```php
Route::get('/info', function (Request $request) {


    echo url('/'); // gives '://project.test'
    echo '<br>';
    echo request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost(); // gives 'http://project.test'

    // This will lead me to 'http://project.test/://project.test/redirect'
    // return redirect('/redirect');
});
```

I have the same problem with the static resources.

Config:

- `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://project.test')` in `config/app.php`
- `APP_URL=http://project.test` in the `.env` file.

I certainly missed something, but so far I couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: What is the 'url' in your `config/app.php` file?

Comment: `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://project.test')`. And `APP_URL=http://project.test`
 in the `.env` file.

Comment: Your config seems fine. Can you share a snippet of code where you use url()?

Comment: `APP_URL` is only used by the CLI, it does nothing when you are running via a webserver

Comment: I added an example in the description.

Comment: if you have copied some dirs from another source, try from cmd prompt "php artisan cache:clear" ,  "php artisan route:clear"  ,  "php artisan config:clear"  and  "php artisan view:clear"

Comment: Have you tried `return redirect('redirect');`

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... Yes I tried, same result :(

Comment: @Eric: done, same results...

Comment: Can you show your `redirect` route.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... `return redirect('redirect');` brings me to `http://project.test/://project.test/redirect`.

Comment: But it has to be  your route in routing file, right?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... Well I do have a `Route::get('/redirect', (...))` in my routing file, and it should lead to this, but as the URL is not properly wrote during the redirection, it always leads to a 404... The problem is the same no matter what route I want to redirect to: the root URL is always duplicated, without its scheme...

Comment: try with localhost. use http://localhost/test/public/xxx/yyy assuming main index.php is located in laravel/test/public (change with your dir location).     
don't forget change in .env APP_URL=http://localhost   and SESSION_DOMAIN='localhost'
and clear all caches (routes, views,  config) like I mentionned.

Comment: @Eric is it possible to do that even if I'm using Homestead?

Comment: The local web server handle localhost or 127.0.0.1. Homestead (or laracast I use) modifies the host file on windows. It allow to have a url that looks like a real server. type localhost , or localhost/project/public in url browser and see what appends. ...Can you post somewhere your routes/web.php and your host and lmhost.sam in  windows\System32\drivers\etc dir ?

Comment: another test : named route , assuming you have a route like : Route::get('/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz' , 'yourdir\YourController@methodname') -> name('routeName1')    try this : return redirect()->route('routeName1');

Comment: @Eric In my hosts file I've set this: `192.168.10.10       project.test`. There's nothing in my lmhost.sam file. Here is an part of my routes/web.php file: https://pastebin.com/hbzjhUmX

Comment: Answer updated, take a look.

Answer (score -1):

when you redirect check if you wrote : "Redirect::home()" , try  "return Redirect::home()" (note the return)

I tested your routes, and it's working nicelly for me.
I give you my config,just replace "tlara" wich is my project name with your's : "project"

### in host.sam

127.0.0.1      tlara.test           #laragon magic! (note is not my ip 192.xx.xx, 127.0.0.1 is universal localhost)

### in .env

APP_URL=http://localhost
..
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1   (i don't know if it is revelant)
..
SESSION_DOMAIN='localhost'

### clear

clear caches (routes, caches, view) (may be useless)

### test

tlara.test/info
127.0.0.1/info
localhost/tlara/public/info

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the answeer, I replaced `return redirect('/redirect');` by `return Redirect::home()`, I got an "InvalidArgumentException - Route [home] not defined.". When I try with `Redirect::to('')` or `Redirect::to('/')`, I have the same problems as before (redirected to `http://project.test/://project.test`).